# Companion materials for studying Goodfellow's Deep Learning book

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, references

After studying the basics of machine learning, I want to follow the deep learning book of Ian Goodfellow. To have a better understanding of the book and make clearer the points that I could not get well, I would like to follow video lectures (which are based on the same book, maybe chapter by chapter etc.)

I know that it exists a website for that: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/ and also a video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi7lACKOUao&list=PLsXu9MHQGs8df5A4PzQGw-kfviylC-R9b&ab_channel=AlenaKruchkova.

Are there any other materials (video, pdf, course lecture, slide etc.) that explain the book in more detail (particularly the details of calculations while passing from one equation to another, or deriving something etc.)?